# Does Adobe Premiere CC support export via network?

Tags: adobe, video

From [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10906/distributed-rendering-in-adobe-premiere-cs-6) I know that Premiere does not support distributed rendering, but from what I understand distributed rendering is spreading the render onto multiple computers to speed it up. My workflow is a little bit different.

I have a pretty powerful desktop computer which I'd like to use to edit video and then a less powerful notebook which I'd like to use to do the actual export, so that my primary PC does not slow down during that.

**Is it possible to do the editing on one PC and then, without manually copying the project and the files, do the export on a different computer in Adobe Premiere CC?**

Comment: Depending on how fast your editing computer and also the attached disks are, for me it sometimes works to pass the export to media encoder, since I can still continue to edit while the export is running. You can define this export folder on a shared volume of the laptop and define this folder as a watch folder in mediaencoder on the laptop. That way the "main" editing computer will just do the initial export and the laptop will start compressing additional formats.

Comment: The speed is my problem. I am an amateur who never needs to edit while exporting, but the process hogs down my PC enough to make it uncomfortable to use.

Comment: Then I don't understand the point. You never need to continue editing... So why don't you just let the desktop export the film and that's it? Or, if the laptop is even faster than the laptop: completely work with premiere on the laptop?

Comment: The process of exporting slows down my PC a lot. Not enough to make it completely unusable, but enough to make doing anything other than idle internet browsing impossible, so that's why I'd like to do the editing on my main PC and the exporting on the machine I don't use.

Comment: The question would be why you don't do the others things you have to do on the laptop. But maybe that would be too simple :)

Comment: Yea, that would be too simple :). I considered it, but I guess SSD in my main PC spoiled me too much! I try to avoid using the laptop simply because it's noticeable slower than my primary computer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not possible natively. However, [Deadline](http://docs.thinkboxsoftware.com/products/deadline/7.1/1_User%20Manual/manual/overview.html), a third-party render management system, does support Premiere Pro projects via Adobe [Media Encoder](http://docs.thinkboxsoftware.com/products/deadline/7.1/1_User%20Manual/manual/app-mediaencoder.html) jobs. Even distributed rendering may be possible.

Comment: I'm head of support over here at Thinkbox. Sadly, AME is a one project per machine sort of beast. But PP and oddly enough Final Cut ought to work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so what I do in similar cases like yours is having the entire project on an external disk (project & video data). Make sure you have identical versions of premiere and all the used plug-ins installed in both premiere instances. Just finish the work and take the project to another computer. I make a local copy of the project file before opening it on the new computer. Open the project, reconnect the video data to the new file path (which might have changed due to the "other" PC mapping the external drive differently) and start export process on the other PC. Not as comfortable as network render but serves the purpose of freeing another PC from the workload. Especially if you have a fast external disk I/O like esata, usb3 or thunderbolt, this works nicely.

If you are positive you have reached a final editing version, you can use the project trimmer to slim the project to the actual video files you used before copying it to the external disk to minimize disk space usage. Having all the data on an external disk doubles as a backup though and therefore also has advantages.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Premiere Pro CC does not support network rendering/distributed rendering, only After Effects does but on a network level such that you would need to copy the files, or host the files (exact same versions), and then your main computer would also be involved in the process.

Premiere isn't really designed for render farms nor this kind of workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Premiere is designed for network renders through After Effects.  Here's the problem: File Location, right?
No longer!!
Share the drive, map the drive to the same letter on the other machine.  The drive should be external of your system drive, if not, get two nice heavy hammers you can hold with one hand and hit yourself in the head until you find some sense... ...I'm just kidding by the way.  We've all done that one.  If you placed the whole thing on your main drive, copy it to an external, leave the original on your main drive as a backup.  Share the external drive.  Now map it to the same location (Drive letter) on your other system.  Now run the job in media encoder.  Ta and Da, you can use your main system while another system handles the grunt work; you'll still have some performance dedicated to file movement.  If you render on your slower system, it'll take longer.

AE can split up the Rendering Decompression step.  Once you have a folder of images, you can compress it with the audio added in AME much faster.  By splitting up the work, you can capitalize on all your resources.  Renderfarm in AE, and then use AME on the stronger or less used machine.  It'll cut the workload for both machines, and allow you to use your network backbone to transfer data.  I also recommend you attach a second network card, then link them together over an ad-hoc intranet by setting the ip and subnet tight.  If you disconnect the second (render only) machine from your router, it will only have intranet, and your computer will pass files to it faster, without confusing nic's.  Now your main internet connection won't bog down either.  If you can add a fibre based connection in this manner, you're gold, but you can get away with USB3 interconnection devices, or even thunderbolt for faster transfers.

Answer (score 0):

Without having source file sitting on the computer it's not possible, although if you have a drive shared and that path is mounted on your notebook like it was a drive, Media Encoder will recognize it and consider it as an actual drive thus making it possible. create watch folder with AME on your note book and once you have finish you save as you project in that folder and it'll start automatically (the sequence you want to export should be the only one at the first level of you project window in Premiere Pro, the other ones, if there are, should be stored in bin folder, otherwise they will prompt in AME). Enjoy ;)